# PHP + jQuery/AJAX form submit and loading result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this form with multiple radio buttons. Exactly 3 inputs per person. I am able to submit and store it to database with ajax and no problems there. My problem is really getting correct info back after submit. In my process.php I'm checking that if the same person has two or more inputs checked it will not insert that data. So that's working correctly too when submitting, only right stuff goes to my db. But when I try get info back from that same file with ajax it always says "Error - 1 per person". I guess the reason is that because I check with $_POST-data and after submit that second time it loads process.php all those $_POST-inputs are equal.

So how could I get that correct info back? Maybe some jQuery? I have no idea at the moment.

Here is some code

**JS -part**

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("[name=insert]").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    submitForm();   
    ("#content").load("process.php")
     return false; } ); });

   // Function to do the AJAX
   function submitForm() {
   $.ajax({type:"POST", url:"process.php", data:$("#myform").serialize(), cache:false, timeout:10000,
         success: function() {
            alert("Succeeded"); 
                      },                           
          error: function () {
                 alert("Error");
                           }
                                    }); }
```

**process.php**

```
   $person3=$_POST['person3'];
   $person2=$_POST['person2'];
   $person1=$_POST['person1'];

   if(($person3 == $person2) OR ($person3 == $person1) OR ($person2 == $person1)){

    echo "<p align='center'>Error - 1 per person</p>";
}
else{

  //sql query   
}
```

Comment: Simply check for `isset()` on the post values, before making a comparison, to ensure that they won't all be equal. Also, the `success` callback of your ajax function will provide you with whatever data you need from your SQL query's completion. Simply return something from the process.pph file, and pass it to `success:function(data)`, where `(data)` is what you returned. Then you can do `$('#content').html(data)`. Remove the loading, no reason for it.

Comment: Woah, this should have been posted as an answer. Nice work on it.

Comment: Ohgodwhy: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks! Already tried isset()-check before but didn't really do it because then it didn't even return that "Error - 1 per person" when needed. But that success callback was just what I needed. Awesome!